# Notepad++ Syntax colouring: Delimiter style closes on end-of-line

Tags: syntax, notepad++

I'm making a new colouring syntax for Notepad++.

I'd like to detect and mark the "some_method_name" in the following text:

```
method::some_method_name
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, ...
```

I wanted to use a "Delimiter style" with "::" as *Open* param, and End of line as *Close*  param. But I don't know how to write this "end of line".

I tried `\n`, `\\n`, `\n\r`, `\\n\\r`, `\\r\\n`, but none are working.

How to approach this syntax colouring ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ((EOL)) to do that.